# web.js and npm express - Warning: express.createServer() is deprecated

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2

Noob - and first - question to stackoverflow -

I am running ubuntu on EC2 t1 micro instance - the following is from my web.js file and below that output from node web.js command in command line.

What substitution(s) do I need to make to prevent Warning below?

Thanks in advance,

David

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var htmlfile = "index.html";

var app = express.createServer(express.logger());

app.get('(/', function(request, response) {
    var html = fs.readFileSync(htmlfile).toString();
    response.send(html);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

[ubuntu@ip-10-185-34-47:~/bitstarter]$node web.js

Warning: express.createServer() is deprecated, express
applications no longer inherit from http.Server,
please use:

```
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();
```

Listening on 8080

Edit: Warning problem has been fixed. First reply below did the trick.

New Errors - same exact command: node web.js ----

/home/ubuntu/bitstarter/node_modules/express/lib/utils.js:312
  return new RegExp('^' + path + '$', sensitive ? '' : 'i');
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(//?$/: Unterminated group
    at new RegExp ()
    at Object.exports.pathRegexp (/home/ubuntu/bitstarter/node_modules/express/lib/utils.js:312:56)
    at new Route (/home/ubuntu/bitstarter/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:35:23)
    at Router.route (/home/ubuntu/bitstarter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:295:15)
    at Router.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/ubuntu/bitstarter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:308:16)
    at Function.app.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/ubuntu/bitstarter/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:414:26)
    at Object. (/home/ubuntu/bitstarter/web.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

This error came up after I logged out and back in after a few hours but I hadn't made any changes to the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning already shows the solution.

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.use(express.logger());
```